# Any query/way available to search a word in Database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to Developing area. For my product, I need to handle nearly 100 tables. I feel risk to find a single word available in the DB. Is there any query available to search a word available in any table in the DB. And the result gives the table name if possible.

Thank you...

Comment: Is it required to do this once or repeatedly.

Comment: @Deepak, could you accept the answer that was useful to you ?

Comment: @ Naveen kumar : I am required to do this repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

there is a FULL TEXT search option in mysql.. but it works on one table at a time.

to search multiple tables you will need to either write some dynamic query, or denormalize

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you have phpMyAdmin. Select your database, and than the Search tab. You can select one or more tables to search in. If you leave the field name empty, it searches in any field. Than you can view the results by table. (Note: I tested in phpMyAdmin v3.2)

Answer (score 0):

for standalone solution i suggest this function :

```
<?php
function search_all_databases($search_token){
    $db = array(
          'host'     => 'localhost'
         ,'user'     => 'root'
         ,'pass'     => ''
         ,'database' => 'buns'
         ,'prefix'   => ''
         ,'type'     => 'mysqli'
    );

    $mysqli = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['database']);

    $output = "<table><thead><tr><th> Database Name </th><th> Occurence </th></tr></thead>";

    $sql = "show tables";
    $ret = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if( 0 < $ret->num_rows ){
        $output.= '<tbody>';

        while( $row = $ret->fetch_array() ){
            $output.= '<tr>';
            $sql_search_fields = Array();

            $table  = $row[0];
            $output.= '<td>'.$table.'</td>';

            $sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table;
            $ret2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
            if( 0 < $ret2->num_rows ){
                while( $row2 = $ret2->fetch_array() ){
                    $colum = $row2[0];
                    $sql_search_fields[] = "`".$colum."` like('%".$search_token."%')";
                }

                $ret2->close();
            }

            if( 0 < count( $sql_search_fields ) ){
                $search = "select * from ".$table." where ";
                $search.= implode(" OR ", $sql_search_fields );

                $rs3 = $mysqli->query($search);
                $output.= '<td>'.$rs3->num_rows.'</td>';
            }else{
                $output.= '<td>0</td>';
            }

            if( 0 < $rs3->num_rows ){
                $rs3->close();
            }

            $output.= '</tr>';
        }

        $output.= '</tbody>';
        $ret->close();
    }

    return $output;
}

echo search_all_databases('a');
```

This function depends on mysqli, you can change it to another database method like mysql.

Also this will output an table with the results. if you would like to use the results in another location i'd suggest putting all the results in an array or so.